# Prevent value of SQL column from going negative with a trigger?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a table, let's say it's got two columns, `person` and `n_dollars`, where `n_dollars` represents the amount of dollars paid or received, something like

| Person | n_dollars |
| --- | --- |
| First | 100 |
| First | -100 |
| Second | 100 |
| Second | 200 |

And so the total amount of money someone has can be found by summing over `n_dollars`. I want to prevent this value from ever going negative, so if we attempt to insert

| Person | n_dollars |
| --- | --- |
| First | -1 |

We receive an error. How can I accomplish this? I'm thinking I would do this with a trigger, something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER prevent_negative
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON table
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.n_dollars + SUM(n_dollars) THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION
END
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to add a CHECK constraint to your table, or include one in the table definition when you create it.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name 
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_dollars_positive 
CHECK ( n_dollars>= 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not postgresql, but if you really want a trigger to create a log or email the error data, I'd do something similar in SQL Server

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER t_insert
    ON dbo.[table]
INSTEAD OF INSERT  
AS
BEGIN
    IF(ROWCOUNT_BIG() = 0)
        RETURN;

    declare @persona varchar(100)
    select @persona = persona from inserted

    DECLARE @money decimal
    select @money = [money] from inserted 


    IF((SELECT SUM([MONEY]) FROM [table] WHERE PERSONA = @PERSONA) + @MONEY >= 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [TABLE] ([PERSONA], [MONEY])
        SELECT [PERSONA], [MONEY] FROM inserted
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'the balance cannot be negative'
    END


END
```

Comment: The question clearly states postgres, this answer is off-topic

Answer (score 0):

First off your trigger is **not valid** Postgres. Postgres does not have code in a trigger instead the [Trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createtrigger.html) just invokes a [Trigger Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html). (Your trigger looks Oracle.) The expression `NEW.n_dollars + SUM(n_dollars)` is also invalid as sum requires accessing the table, also prohibited by Oracle, but acceptable in Postgres.  
Unfortunately a check constraint will not work. The task is not to prevent a row being inserted from having a negative value but prevent `sum(n_dollars)` from going negative and aggravate functions are not allowed in `check` constraints.  So something like: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ea9e5384a3d7e6123ec62d16b07eda4f))

```
create or replace 
function prevent_negative()
   returns trigger 
  language plpgsql
as $$
declare 
    l_n_dollars numeric; 
begin 
    select sum(n_dollars) 
      into l_n_dollars
      from test                   -- replace with actual table name
     where person = new.person ; 
      
   if l_n_dollars + new.n_dollars < 0 then 
      raise exception 'Cannot apply % dollers to person %. Would result in total dollers less than 0'
                    , new.n_dollars, new.person;
   end if;
  
  return new; 
 end; 
$$; 
      
create or replace trigger test_bir  
    before insert 
        on test                   -- replace with actual table name 
     for each row 
     when ( new.n_dollars < 0 )
        execute function prevent_negative();
```

As an alternative Postgres provides the ability to just *ignore* the violating row. However typically you suppress the exception being raised without any type of notification. So while the row would not be stored neither is there any notification. The demo also includes a example.